cant pass the data to useForm
i have this component that in the end should return date on change as string YYYY-MM-DD
the DateInput
import React, { useState, useRef, ChangeEvent, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Select, SelectContent, SelectItem, SelectTrigger, SelectValue } from "@/components/ui/select";

export default function DateInput({ onDateChange, setCurrentDateType }:
    { onDateChange: (combinedDate: string) => void, setCurrentDateType: (type: string) => void }) {
    const [date, setDate] = useState({ day: '', month: '', year: '' });
    const [calendarType, setCalendarType] = useState<'ميلادي' | 'هجري'>('هجري');
    const yearRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (date.day && date.month && date.year) {
            const combinedDate = `${date.year}-${date.month}-${date.day}`;
            onDateChange(combinedDate);
            setCurrentDateType(calendarType);
        }
    }, [date, calendarType]);

    const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const numValue = value.replace(/\D/g, '');

        let newValue = numValue;
        if (name === 'day') newValue = numValue.slice(0, 2);
        if (name === 'year') newValue = numValue.slice(0, 4);

        setDate(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: newValue }));
        if (name === 'day' && newValue.length === 2) yearRef.current?.focus();
    };

    const handleMonthChange = (value: string) => {
        setDate(prev => ({ ...prev, month: value }));
    };

    const gregorianMonths = [
        "يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "أبريل", "مايو", "يونيو",
        "يوليو", "أغسطس", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر"
    ];

    const hijriMonths = [
        "محرم", "صفر", "ربيع الأول", "ربيع الآخر", "جمادى الأولى", "جمادى الآخرة",
        "رجب", "شعبان", "رمضان", "شوّال", "ذو القعدة", "ذو الحجة"
    ];

    const months = calendarType === 'ميلادي' ? gregorianMonths : hijriMonths;

    return (
        <>
            <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                <Select dir="rtl" onValueChange={(value: 'ميلادي' | 'هجري') => setCalendarType(value)}>
                    <SelectTrigger className="w-24 me-2 py-5 border-2 shadow">
                        <SelectValue placeholder="هجري" />
                    </SelectTrigger>
                    <SelectContent>
                        <SelectItem value="ميلادي">ميلادي</SelectItem>
                        <SelectItem value="هجري">هجري</SelectItem>
                    </SelectContent>
                </Select>
            </div>
            <div className="flex items-center gap-x-2">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="day"
                    value={date.day}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    className="w-12 text-center border-2 border-input shadow rounded-md p-2 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
                    maxLength={2}
                    placeholder="يوم"
                    aria-label="Day"
                />
                <Select dir="rtl" onValueChange={handleMonthChange}>
                    <SelectTrigger className="w-[140px] shadow border-2 border-input py-5">
                        <SelectValue placeholder="الشهر" className='text-start' />
                    </SelectTrigger>
                    <SelectContent>
                        {months.map((month, index) => (
                            <SelectItem key={month} value={(index + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}>
                                {month}
                            </SelectItem>
                        ))}
                    </SelectContent>
                </Select>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="year"
                    value={date.year}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    className="w-16 text-center border-2 border-input shadow rounded-md p-2 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
                    maxLength={4}
                    placeholder="سنه"
                    aria-label="Year"
                    ref={yearRef}
                />
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

I am using it in the page like this
  
interface personal_info {
    birth_date: string | null | Date;
    birth_date_type: string;
}

export type TEventTypes = HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLSelectElement;

interface PersonalDataFormProps {
    nationality_list: string[];
}

export const PersonalDataForm = ({ nationality_list }: PersonalDataFormProps) => {
    const { data, setData, post, errors } = useForm<personal_info>({
        birth_date: "",
        birth_date_type: "هجري",
    });

    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.table(data);
        post(route('regist.personal'));
    };
    return (  ..... 
    <DateInput
        onDateChange={(combinedDate) => setData('birth_date', combinedDate)}
        setCurrentDateType={(type) => setData('birth_date_type', type)}
    />
.....);}

the birth_date_type change in the request but the birthdate itself always null I tried to do this
onDateChange={(combinedDate) => {
    console.log(combinedDate);
    setData('birth_date', combinedDate);
    }
}

and I got the date in the console but not set to the data in the useForm
tyring to set the date (string) to the birth_date in useFrom data
